# Can I compress a RAR file again to reduce its size?

Tags: windows, compression, winrar

I had a 326 MB iso file that I compressed using WinRAR, with the best compression method. It got compressed to 144 MB.

I want to compress more and want it to be limited to something around 22 MB.

Is there a way I can compress the RAR file again? If not, is there any other way out?

Comment: What kind of data does the ISO file contain? Programs? Documents? Music? Video?

Comment: @ David Schwartz It is a software CD,with autorun

Comment: It would be nice if we could compress compressed archives again and again. Every archive would be about 1 byte.

Comment: if all compressed file can be compressed again to reduce its size then we don't need storage at all since the size will become 0 eventually

Comment: As a real-world analogy, astronauts recycle their urine, and animals often eat what they've *ahem* already digested, but there is a limit to this imposed by (possibly geometrically/exponentially) diminishing returns -- otherwise, why would anything or anyone ever starve?  In other words, entropy (not exclusively the Kolmogorov kind, which is especially apropos to file compression, but the (admittedly related) physical kind too) wins.

Comment: @Vandermonde Astronauts might not be the best analogy. Spacecraft have solar panels to collect energy. In theory, we could build machines to rearrange atoms to turn waste into food.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you've already compressed with best compression method, you can't compress further.. Few KB/MB could be digestible, but compressing 144MB compressed data to 22MB: No way!
I'd not say, its impossible. But.. Currently, there's no standard compression algorithm to do this. Sorry!

If 22MB is a limit somewhere (like cloud, storage), you can always use [file splitters](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=file%20splitters) to split this 144MB file into multiple 22MB chunks. File Joiners (often, built-in with file splitters) reverse this process.

Comment: From information theory there's a limit to how much can be compressed. You can't go beyond that.

Comment: I have a 42k archive that contains 4.5 petabyte of data when decompressed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb

Comment: @Zoredache You can't apply Zip Bomb example on practical files. Compression algorithms just remove repeating data. So, create a 10GB file fully filled with 1. Now, compress it. What do you expect? Again compress it to hunt down repeating compression meta data. Do it again-n-again. You'll definitely end up with a KB file. For sure, you can't apply this to practical files!

Comment: That's correct. Zip bombs work same way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1459776/577898 . Our everyday files can't be compressed with that compression ratio.

Comment: why can't the winrar compress the already compressed file ?

Comment: @Suhail Its because compression algorithms fail to find redundant (repeated) bits from already compressed file. So, they can't replace anything with a small representation (this is how compression works)..

Comment: @Zoredache can you tell me the method to do so ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta There's no special method here. You can download 42k zip bombs after a simple Google search. Unzip it. Again unzip one of zips. Don't unzip all, otherwise you'd run out of storage. In the last, you'd find text files. You can reverse engineer it to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can compress the RAR file again?

*Again*? No, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/697781/why-zip-a-zipped-file-doesnt-reduce-its-size/697794#697794) for why a compressed file cannot be compressed further. If anything, re-compressing an already compressed file may even *increase* the resulting file.

> If not, is there any other way out?

Your best bet is to either tweak the WinRAR settings to the file you were trying to compressing, or to use a better compression algorithm. [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) supports several different powerful algorithms, and by tuning them just right, you could *potentially* get a big increase in savings over RAR.

I usually like to keep everything set to the maximum (figure 1). It takes longer to compress, but it’s usually worth it.

You can also try [nanozip](http://www.nanozip.net/). It is an experimental archiver (read alpha) and runs *very* slowly, but gives shockingly good compression most of the time.

Of course, as always, compression results will depend on your file(s). You said you are compressing an ISO which is essentially just the contents of the files with little file-system overhead. Depending on the nature of the files, you may get some decent compression, but if it is an installation disk, then the contents of the main software are likely already compressed, so you won’t get that much more from the remaining files.

---

**Figure 1**: 7-Zip settings set to maximum compression

[image: 7-Zip settings set to maximum compression]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PC with RAM higher than 3 GB and processor about 3 GHz, use [KGB Archiver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kgbarchiver/).

At maximum compression and PAQ6 algorithm you’ll be able to reduce a file's size to a fourth or fifth of the original – but it's a very slow process.

Answer (score 0):

It might make a little more sense to look at why you can't compress it further. 
In an oversimplified statement, compression would work like this:

Document Pre-Compression (110 Characters):

```
this is a document that has not been compressed. After this document is compressed the length will be shorter.
```

Same document, Post Compression (103 Characters):

```
1:this
2:document
3:compressed
1 is a 2 that has not been 3. After 1 2 is 3 the length will be shorter.
```

In this particular example, a moderate level of compression is applied, if you had more time (computer power) to count occurrences of words, you could increase the compression of this statement by pulling out the word "is". But even large amounts of CPU time can only compress documents a fraction further, leaps from 110 MB to 22 MB aren't possible unless there are a lot of things to replace in the first compression pass..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd prefer using the best possible method for compression cause I've tried recompression of a file that I've compressed lightly. My file didn't changed it's size.

But when I've decompressed it and then recompressed it using the best method, then I came out with flying 
colors

So plz do the heaviest compression

Answer (score -1):

Well, of course we can't compress an already compressed file. But still, believe me. A compressed file is way better and cheaper deal than being held up with no compression.

If it's just a matter of storage problem then I suppose you must buy a new sdcard/pen drive or must delete unwanted items and copies.

And if it's a matter of uploading then I prefer using a Wi-Fi and leaving your phone undisturbed if it will take half hour or more to upload.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, the information in your answer is already present in another answer. You should have upvote that one instead posting your own. I realize you don't have enough reputation to do that, so wait until you do.

Answer (score -5):

First use the winrar to compress it with the best mode. Then archive it with 7zip. I tried it with gta sanandreas with a size 5.79 GB and after compression it got reduced to a memory of 12MB. Believe me, it's working.

Comment: Might work with PAQ ([see other answer](http://superuser.com/a/576095/219095)), sure as hell won’t work with 7-Zip and friends.

Comment: I highly doubt that's possible.

Comment: It will work in rare cases. There are compression methods which can decrease size every time you compress the compressed file ([PAQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAQ) was mentioned by @DanielB). WinRAR and 7Zip don't use such methods by default. So the size can increase in place of decreasing while doing this.